# Putting returned value in parameter using Java

Tags: java

Create a new program called assignLetterGrade.

Prompt the user (a student) to enter their name.

Create a method called calculateAvgScore which should prompt the user to enter 3 scores (integer values greater than or equal to zero) and calculate the average, dropping any fractional part. Then, return the integer value to main.

Once the average is returned, print the student's name and their average score using printf command.

Create another method called printLetterGrade which should accept the average score as a parameter and return the letter grade.

Use if…else if…else statements to print the student's grade (‘A’, ‘B’, ‘C’, ‘D’, or ‘F’).

Grade Scale:

90-100 - A

80-89 - B

70-79 - C

60-69 - D

0-59 - F

I am struggling with the printLetterGrade method. I am not sure how to put the average score as a parameter. I tried inserting the caculateAvgScore method into printLetterGrade, but it did not work. It also does not work in the main method. Please help me!

```
import java.util.*;//to use Scanner
public class assignLetterGrade
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter your name: ");
        String name = console.next();
        int average = calculateAvgScore();
        System.out.printf("Name: " + name + "/nAverage Score: %d", average);
        string letter = printLetterGrade(int avg);//does not work
    }
    public static int calculateAvgScore()//calculates average score of user
    {
        System.out.println("Enter 3 scores.");
        int total = 0;
        int average = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
        {
            Scanner console = new Scanner (System.in);
            System.out.print("Enter score");
            int number = console.nextInt();
            total += number;
            average = total/3;
        }
        return average;
    }
    public static String printLetterGrade(int avg)//prints letter grade of average score, does not work
    {
        String letter = "";
        if (avg < 100 && avg >= 90)
        {
            letter = "A";
        }
        else if (avg < 89 && avg >= 80)
        {
            letter = "B";
        }
        else if (avg < 79 && avg >= 70)
        {
            letter = "C";
        }
        else if (avg < 69 && avg >= 60)
        {
            letter = "D";
        }
        else 
        {
            letter = "F";
        }
        return letter;
    }
}
```

Comment: Compare `printLetterGrade(int avg);` with `System.out.print("Enter your name: ");` What difference do you see between the two in how the parameter is used?

Comment: On a separate note, I get awarded an `F` if I get 100 in each test.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/passing-parameters

Comment: You should test against ``avg <= 100`` or else a score of 100 will not be detected.

Answer (score 0):

String needs to be init cap as it is a class, pass actual variable instead of its definition to the `printletterGrade()`

```
string letter = printLetterGrade(int avg);
```

To

```
String letter = printLetterGrade(average);
```

Please share the error message as well?